# TypeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'",)

Tags: python, html, mysql

i am using python 2.7

i have to connect a mysql database and a html form page using python

[image]

when i type in all the spaces like this
[image]

the form gives me the correct answers but when when i do it like this
[image]

It gives me this error

```
TypeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'",)
```

How can i take the correct results even if i am not fill all the fields?

My code:

```
 # ----- CONFIGURE YOUR EDITOR TO USE 4 SPACES PER TAB ----- #
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python
import pymysql as db
import settings

def connection():
    ''' Use this function to create your connections '''
    con = db.connect(
        settings.mysql_host, 
        settings.mysql_user, 
        settings.mysql_passwd, 
        settings.mysql_schema,
        charset='utf8',
        use_unicode=True)

    return con
def searchSong(titlos,etos_par,etaireia):


    # Create a new connection   
    con=connection()

    #create a cursor to the connection
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    cur.execute ("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

    cur.execute("SELECT tragoudi.titlos, tragoudi.etos_par, cd_production.etaireia FROM tragoudi JOIN singer_prod ON tragoudi.titlos=singer_prod.title JOIN cd_production ON singer_prod.cd=cd_production.code_cd GROUP BY tragoudi.titlos HAVING tragoudi.titlos LIKE %s AND tragoudi.etos_par LIKE %s AND cd_production.etaireia LIKE %s",(titlos,etos_par,etaireia))
    con.commit()




    for row in cur.fetchall():
         return [(row,)]
```

AND

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0], 'lib'))
from bottle import route, run, static_file, request
import pymysql as db
import settings
import app

def renderTable(tuples):
    printResult = """<style type='text/css'> h1 {color:red;} h2 {color:blue;} p {color:green;} </style>
    <table border = '1' frame = 'above'>"""

    header='<tr><th>'+'</th><th>'.join([str(x) for x in tuples[0]])+'</th></tr>'
    data='<tr>'+'</tr><tr>'.join(['<td>'+'</td><td>'.join([str(y) for y in row])+'</td>' for row in tuples[1:]])+'</tr>'

    printResult += header+data+"</table>"
    return printResult
@route('/searchSong')
def searchSongWEB():
    titlos = request.query.titlos
    etos_par = request.query.etos_par
    etaireia = request.query.etaireia

    table = app.searchSong(titlos,etos_par,etaireia)
    print "<html><body>" + renderTable(table) + "</body></html>"
    return "<html><body>" + renderTable(table) + "</body></html>"


@route('/:path')
def callback(path):
    return static_file(path, 'isto')

@route('/')
def callback():
    return static_file("index.html", 'isto')


run(host='localhost', port=settings.web_port, reloader=True, debug=True)
```

Comment: Which line of your code is giving this error?

Comment: You should really use templates rather than building the HTML strings yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you're trying to index into `None`, which most likely happens in `renderTable(tuples)` if `tuples` is `None`:

```
header='<tr><th>'+'</th><th>'.join([str(x) for x in tuples[0]])+'</th></tr>'
#                                             here! ---^
```

Probably `app.searchSong()` returns `None` in case it didn't find anything. If it would return an empty sequence, you would get an `IndexError` instead. You need to handle the case when the search returns no results.